# xargs how to put result {} into $(cmd {})?

Tags: bash, xargs

for example:
`find /usr/lib -maxdepth 1 -type l -iname "*libblas*"|xargs -I{} echo "{} =>" $(realpath {})`
I would like it to output:

```
/usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf=>/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3gf.0
/usr/lib/libblas.so=>/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3gf.0
/usr/lib/libblas.a=>/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.a
```

This will not work because the value in `$()` is expanded before the script actual running.

Is there any way I can achieve this result? without loop in bash?

Comment: [Also posted on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717083/xargs-how-to-put-result-into-cmd). Don't do that, it's rude.

Comment: I only know this site exist after I posted. But when I tried to remove the stackoverflow one, some users have already answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way,

```
find /usr/lib -maxdepth 1 -type l -iname "*lib*" -print \
   | xargs -P1 -I{} -- sh -c 'echo -n " {} => " && realpath "{}"'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  find /usr/lib -maxdepth 1 -type l -iname "*libblas*"|xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo "{} =>" $(realpath {})'
```

Basically you have to start a subshell.  FWIW I don't know what realpath is; if it's an alias or a function your subshell might need to be bash.

Comment: Note that while this should work here, this is not a general solution: file names that contain shell special characters will be interpreted as shell code. In particular, if you don't have full control over the file names, this is a gaping security hole.